# Which VirtualBox network scenario to chose for single demo VM with webserver

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have to setup a demo system for a web application with these requirements:
On a Windows device (laptop) a virtual Ubuntu (16.04) system is to be set up using VirtualBox 5.0.40. This guest system contains a web server which should be reachable both from the host Windows laptop and from a very limited (one or two) number of other devices/clients in the same network. There is no other virtual machine running on the host system.

As far as I see there are two different approaches:

- Using NAT with port forwarding. Incoming HTTP requests from other devices would use the host's IP address and served from the web server within the guest system.
- Using a bridged networking approach in which the guest system would get its own IP in the work (which then other devices would use).

I've found a very interesting blog article which seems to be in favor of the first solution: [Oracle VM VirtualBox: Networking options and how-to manage them](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/networking-in-virtualbox-v2) However, it seems they do not take other devices/clients trying to connect to the guest into consideration.

My main concern is reliability and stability, performance being the second priority, easy setup maybe the third. So, which approach would you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you gave gives a few hints on when to use one or the other: "NAT Networking characteristics: Great when guests are clients, Not good for guests as servers" and "Bridged Networking characteristics: Good for clients or server guests". It doesn't explain why, but there are a few reasons:

- the only two downsides of bridged that I know are that 1) it needs extra configuration, and 2) it exposes the entirety of the guest to the network, so you should firewall the guest "on the inside" (whereas the NAT will only expose the ports you explicitly forward).
- on the other hand, bridged allows you to expose even ports that conflict with the host (e.g. you if you already had a web server on the host, you couldn't forward port 80/443 to the guest), and should, in theory at least, be slightly faster as there's not NAT step involved; or at least, if there are issues with the VirtualBox's NAT module, it would avoid them.

I use NAT for one-off or pure clients, and bridged mode for long-lived guests where I want to expose services. But I think, for small traffic scenarios, both would work fine. Up to you whether you want to configure bridging (and deal with acquiring an IP address for the guest).

Answer (score 0):

Asussuming the availability of free addresses which can be assigned the bridged VM, I'd prefer bridged,  For one thing as the article says

> However, how does another computer initiate a connection into a Guest?
>   e.g. connecting to a web server running in the Guest. This is not
>   (normally) possible using NAT mode as there is no route into the Guest
>   OS
>   That is VBox sets up the NAT from the VM to the real network - but you would have to set up the translation from the outside network to the VM.  Its not worth it 
>   But that said for you answer I dont think either way affects reliability stability or performance.